# Sending vCard update

Tags: ios, xmpp, vcf-vcard, xmppframework

I'm currently playing with the XMPPFramework for iOS and I had the idea to let users make their own profile, based on vCards. I've made a screen where they can enter some information, such as date of birth, first/last name etc. When they are done they press the 'save' button.

What I would like to do, is to letting know everyone that's subscribed to this user that his vCard changed but I'm not sure how to do this. I've already tried to send a vcard-temp:x:update stanza but the message didn't arrive on my other device I'm testing with.

Does anyone know how I could do this and which method I could use?

Comment: hey i m working on v-cards or avatars.. can u help me in that

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know about vCard changes,

You can only know about photo updates via XEP: 0153

This xep uses the presence to send the photo there.

Comment: hey i m working on v-cards or avatars.. can u help me in that.. i just implemented the v-card. but not working for me

Comment: now i have done the v cards and update profile pic. but i just want to know one thing that how to save that pic and username in existing core data(XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject). how to delete the roster just from the core data.

Comment: you need to set the photo element ?

Comment: i have already set that but i want to store the pic and user in core data